# Boost asio-acceptor unblocks without a new connection?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using the C++ boost asio library, where I listen to new connections on the socket. On getting a connection I process the request and then listen for a new connection on another socket in a loop.

```
while (true)
{
    tcp::socket soc(this->blitzIOService);
    this->blitzAcceptor.listen();
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    this->blitzAcceptor.accept(soc,ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        // Some error occured
        cerr << "Error Value: " << ec.value() << endl;
        cerr << "Error Message: " << ec.message() << endl;
        soc.close();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        this->HandleRequest(soc);
        soc.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
        soc.close();
    }
}
```

According to my understanding it should always block at **this->blitzAcceptor.accept(soc,ec);** and everytime a new connection is made it should handle it in **this->HandleRequest(soc);** and again block at **this->blitzAcceptor.accept(soc,ec);**

But what I see is this that for the first time it will block at **this->blitzAcceptor.accept(soc,ec)** and when a new connection is made it will handle the request, but instead of blocking again at **this->blitzAcceptor.accept(soc,ec)** it will go ahead into **this->HandleRequest(soc);** and block at **soc.receive();** inside.

This doesn't happen always, but happens most of the time. What could be the reason to this behavior, and how can I ensure that it always block at this->blitzAcceptor.accept(soc,ec) until a new request is made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could be the reason to this
>   behavior?

This behavior is entirely dependent on the client code. If it connects, but does not send a request, the server with block when receiving data.

> how can I ensure that it always block
>   at this->blitzAcceptor.accept(soc,ec)
>   until a new request is made?

You can't. But your server can initiate a timeout that starts immediately after accepting the connection. If the client does not send a request within that duration, close the socket. To do that, you should switch to using asynchronous methods rather than synchronous methods.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation "This behavior is entirely dependent on the client code. If it connects, but does not send a request, the server with block when receiving data." is correct. I am writing a Http Server and was under the impression that the browser will make a new connection only when it makes a new request. Here I noticed that it does make a new new connection, without having any request to send. As of now I serve the request and close the connection. Maybe for this reason it makes a new connection just as an optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you're not blocking on a `read(2)` call for the file descriptor that you are `listen(2)`'ing on vs the file descriptor that you `accept(2)`'ed. I think if you print out the file descriptor numbers you'll very quickly find your problem.